# Intellij: Change JUnit Test Class template

Tags: templates, junit, intellij-idea

I would like to customize the JUnit Test class template however I cannot find it anywhere in settings.  [This guy](http://devnet.jetbrains.com/thread/282158) has the same problem.  I can't find anything in File Templates or Live Templates.  I'm using Intellij 11.

Comment: Does http://devnet.jetbrains.com/thread/286786 answer your question?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

This is now solved in the latest IntelliJ IDEA / Android Studio. Go to:

```
Settings
-Editor
-File and Code Templates
-Code (tab)
-JUnit4 Test Class
```

edit the code in the right window.

[image: Image of the dialog from above description]

Comment: nice, exactly what I was after

Comment: Doesn't work for kotlin files. At least, in Android Studio 4.1.1

Answer (score 1):

The link provided by CrazyCoder suggests that this is not directly possible but that I you need to add if statements to the Class File Type template.  I will probably split the template in two using a big if-else.