# IntelliJ: How to add JavaDoc to an existing class using the "Class" template

Tags: java, templates, intellij-idea, javadoc

When I create a new test class with <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd> in IntelliJ (using 13.1.3), the new class has no class JavaDoc.

I do have a template for new Class, and for new Interface, but those do not get used when I create a new test class as described above.

Also, when I go to the new test class's declaration and insert JavaDoc as per /** + <kbd>ENTER</kbd>, then my templates aren't used either.

This works in Eclipse, and I am looking to have the same level of convenience in IntelliJ.

Any way to make this work?

Comment: It's weird, I've tested this moments ago on IDEA 12, and it creates javadoc for test classes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Intellij: Change JUnit Test Class template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14726196/intellij-change-junit-test-class-template) shows how to edit the template for Test classes.

I didn't see it because it's in the "Code" tab, while the template for new classes is in the "templates" tab. The separation seems arbitrary, but whatever.

I still don't know how to add JavaDoc as per template to an existing class that is completely missing JavaDoc.

Answer (score 0):

You can configure templates, that IntelliJ IDEA uses to generate things. It's available in *File | Settings | File Templates*

You can learn more from official documentation here: http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/file-templates.html

Comment: Thanks for the info. I didnt find anything that works with already existing classes.