# Is there a way in Intellj Idea to automatically extend a class while creating a Test?

Tags: java, unit-testing, intellij-idea

When I create a test class about intellj Idea I would like to extend the basic test class directly.

[image]

**Should look like this:**

[image]

is there a way to set that the BaseTest class is extended directly when creating a test? i have searched in the settings and the net but could not find it.

Comment: Using a class hierarchy in tests is kind of a code smell.

Comment: Found an answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14726196/intellij-change-junit-test-class-template

Answer (score 0):

Well, it is beauty of IntelliJ that when you can’t find any shortcut you can create your own.

Go to settings ctrl+alt+s and search for live templates.

Select your preferred language and create your own shortcut by referring already available default shortcut.

Ctrl+shift+t is shortcut to create test of current class. You can modify that per your use.

If you have some doubt, tomorrow morning I will give you one for your case when I turn my laptop on.

Comment: Thanks, but found an answer here...https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14726196/intellij-change-junit-test-class-template

Comment: Same thing I tried to explain :) . Good you got it